# Codeigniter Get the Whatever URL is written after my base_url();

Tags: php, codeigniter

In a Codiginiter is there any way using which i can get the my URL whatever is written after my Base URL  ?

For example :

If my url in the browser is :  `www.example.com/cms/mypage/subpage`

**my base url is** : `www.example.com/`

**Expected output** : cms/mypage/subpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `uri_string()` ?

See here : [CodeIgniter URL Helper Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#uri_string)